# British Maths Olympiad Round 2 2011, Question 3: Is there a more efficient method?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, functional-equations

I've been practicing for the second round of the BMO and I've come across a question for which I think there must be a more efficient solution than I found.

Question 3:
https://bmos.ukmt.org.uk/home/bmo2-2011.pdf

To paraphrase the question, it asks for the number of positive integers $n < 2011$ such that $f(n) = f(2011) = 21$, where $f$ is defined on the positive integers as:

- $f(1) = 1$
- $f(4n) = f(2n)$
- $f(4n+1) = 2f(2n) + 1$
- $f(4n+2) = 2f(2n+1)$
- $f(4n+3) = f(2n+1)$

My method was to note that the only "path" to $21$ is $1,2,5,10,21$. The only positive ints that are mapped to $1$ are of the form $2^a - 1$, and so the only ints mapped to $2$ are of the form $2^b(2^a-1)$, and continuing in this fashion and expanding out, we have the only integers that map to $21$ are those of the form $2^{a+b+c+d+e}-2^{a+b+c+d}+2^{a+b+c}-2^{a+b}+2^e$, where $a,b,c,d,e \geq 1$.

So the number of solutions is equal to the number of sequences $y_1 > y_2 > y_3 > y_4 > y_5 \geq 1$ such that
$$ 2^{y_1} - 2^{y_2} + 2^{y_3} - 2^{y_4} + 2^{y_5} - 1 < 2011$$.

This in turn is equal to the number of sequences $x_1 > x_2 > x_3 > x_4 > x_5 \geq 0$ such that
$$ 2^{x_1} - 2^{x_2} + 2^{x_3} - 2^{x_4} + 2^{x_5} \leq 1005 $$.

Then I defined the function $F_k(n)$ as equal to the number of solutions to the more general problem, where the sum of powers must be $\leq n$ and there are $k$ variables instead of $5$, so the answer is $f_5(1005)$.

Because of the self similarity of the constraint, we have the following recurrence relation:

$$ F_k(n) = \sum_{m\geq 0}{F_{k-1}\left\lfloor\frac{n + (-1)^k2^m}{2^{m+1}}\right\rfloor} $$

With base cases of:

$$ F_1(n) = \lfloor \log_2{n} \rfloor $$
$$ F_k(n) = 0 \text{ when } n \leq 0$$

I implemented both the original problem and my solution in Python to check, and they both gave the same answer, $455$, so my solution is correct. However the paper is intended to be done without a calculator or computer, and it computing the desired value of $F$ by hand seems to need far too many calculations (these questions rarely require drawn out calculations).

So I assume that there is a more efficient method, either in calculating the values of $F$ or by looking at the problem from a completely different angle, both of which I would find extremely helpful.

Comment: In binary terms $f(1)=1,\,f(n00)=f(n0),\,f(n01)=f(n0)1,\,f(n10)=f(n1)0,\,f(n11)=f(n1)0$; you want to count solutions of $f(n)=f(m)=10101,\,m:=11111011011$ with $n<m$. To get from $1$ to $10101$, think about how to add digits on the right.

Comment: Thank you, this is much simpler. I had thought I should consider binary once I had the inequality, but I discounted that approach due to the alternating sum.

Comment: Sorry, that should be $f(n11)=f(n1)$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Write everything in binary. Then we can see that $f(n)$ is the result when we collapse blocks of identical digits in $n$ to one such digit, e.g. $$f(2011)=f(11111011011_2)=10101_2=21.$$
So we want the number of $11$ bit numbers that have $5$ "switches" in the sequence of binary digits, and end in $1$. This is $\binom{11}{5}=462$. However, $7$ of these numbers are at  least $2011$, so the final answer is $455$.

Comment: [Python agrees](https://repl.it/@JosGibbons/BisqueTrustworthyWheel#main.py).